# What are the characters that need to be escaped in Oracle SQL to avoid SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, oracle, security

just want confirming what are the characters that need to be escaped in Oracle SQL to avoid SQL Injection?
So far, I only found this article that seems to answer my question: https://ss64.com/ora/syntax-escape.html.
Yet, as I heard, the amphora '@' character also needs escaping, hence, I thought that above article has incomplete list of characters that needs escaping.
If anyone could point me to the complete list of characters in Oracle SQL that needs escaping, then it will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You avoid SQL injections by not munging query strings.  You start by using *parameters* to pass values into a query.

Comment: Oracle has a built-in package, DBMS_ASSERT, which we can use to validate parameters against SQL Injection. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231). Of course, this only applies if you're using PL/SQL API layer to protect your database.

Comment: [Mandatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: The linked article is not related to SQL injection or security. It is about handling characters that have special meanings which can cause issues in quoted literals, such as the `'` character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Don't try to prevent SQL injection by escaping characters; instead don't use dynamic SQL or generate queries through string concatenation and use properly parameterised queries instead.

---

That [linked page](https://ss64.com/ora/syntax-escape.html) is not about escaping dynamic SQL it is about handling characters that have special meanings in literals (and in some cases its only for a sub-set of user interfaces).

If you have a string literal then this is defined by single-quotes `'` around a string and if you want to use a single-quote in the string literal then you need to escape the single-quote by using a second single-quote.

```sql
SELECT 'The woman''s hat blew off in the wind.' FROM DUAL
```

In the SQL*Plus user interface, you can set the escape character used in `LIKE` queries so that the `%` or `_` characters can be matched that would be otherwise treated as wildcards in the literal:

```sql
SET ESCAPE '\';
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'abc%def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcdef'  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE value LIKE '%\%%';
```

However, you can specify the same thing in the query (which is valid in all user interfaces, not just SQL*Plus):

```sql
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'abc%def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcdef'  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE value LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

The third thing they mention is `&` is used for substitution variables. Many user interfaces do not support substitution variables so this is only a concern for those limited ones that do.

This is a valid SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 'A&B' FROM DUAL
```

However, in SQL*Plus the ampersand `&` character signifies the start of a substitution variable and to ignore it you need to either: redefine the substitution variable's starting character; escape that character; or turn off scanning for substitution variables.

---

> what are the characters that need to be escaped in Oracle SQL to avoid SQL Injection?

All characters are valid in SQL. `SELECT '&@()''"%' FROM DUAL` is a valid statement. It depends on the context of where they occur whether they will cause SQL injection issues.

> Yet, as I heard, the ampersand '@' character also needs escaping

The ampersand `&` character only needs escaping when the user interface supports substitution variables and then only when you want to prevent it being used as a substitution variable; in other SQL user interfaces it has no special meaning.

The at `@` character does not need escaping in SQL.

In general:

- Do not try to escape characters to prevent SQL injection.
- Do not build the query from concatenating strings.
- Use parameterised queries and pass the values into them as bind variables.
- If you have to dynamically provide a schema/table/column name then use [`DBMS_ASSERT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231) to validate those object identifiers (and pass all other values as bind variables).